# How to fix "Server Not Found" on my home wifi while using my laptop with Ubuntu Cinnamon?

Tags: wireless

Ubuntu w Cinnamon successfully loaded new (full install, no partitions for Windows 8.1) onto my wireless laptop yesterday at a meeting in another city where the facility had wifi, yet today back at home I have an issue in that I need help I'm not getting from my ISP on how to get past my Firefox browser message "Server Not Found".  My laptop reads "Wireless ON", my Network name is %100%, my ISPwifi is 100%, ATTO24 is 34%, and belkin.49bb is 20%.  I've gone into my browser general preferences and changed the home page to that of my ISP home page---but I still can't connect.  Any ideas from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried another device on your network ?

post your network config by pressing

Ctrl + Alt + t : open a terminal . 
paste and copy below by marking and pressing Ctrl + c and paste by rigth click (mouse / trackpad ) paste on the terminal
ifconfig -a > /home/your_UserName/Desktop/networkConfig.txt
 :this will put your network config on a text file called networkConfig.txt on your desktop

attache the file

provably you have some problem with the dns .

have you tried a traceroute to google.com ??
in the same terminal 
copy and paste 
traceroute google.com

do the same with the file but use other name like networkTrace.txt